# Looping a function with a timeout in it

Tags: javascript, function, loops

Hi I´m working on an **imageslide**. I allready have the function done. The problem is I want it to loop. After one image has been on screen a certain time the next one should fade in automaticly. I´ve tried to call the function at the end again to loop it but than the images changed rapidley. Seems like the timeout wasn´t notice.

Does anyone has an idea for how to **loop the function without losing the breake between each image?**

Thanks a lot :D

You can view my code here:  https://jsfiddle.net/atqawkds/1/

```js
var imagecount = 1;

function imagegallery() {
  var active = document.getElementById('content' + imagecount);
  active.className = "activecontent";

  setTimeout(function() {
    active.className = 'inactivecontent';
  }, 5000);

  if (imagecount >= 3) {
    imagecount = 0;
  };

  imagecount += 1;

  //I´ve tried to do imagegallery(); here. It didn´t worked like I want it to
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.activecontent {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  min-width: 900px;
  min-height: 500px;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: settoactive 1000ms ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes settoactive {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.inactivecontent {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  min-width: 900px;
  min-height: 500px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: settoinactive 1000ms ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes settoinactive {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#trigger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <img src="https://s17.postimg.org/acwwotncv/img1.jpg" id="content1" class="inactivecontent">
    <img src="https://s17.postimg.org/djrg8guy7/img2.jpg" id="content2" class="inactivecontent">
    <img src="https://s17.postimg.org/ojcnk30sv/img3.jpg" id="content3" class="inactivecontent">
  </div>
  <div id="trigger" onclick="imagegallery()">Press to change image</div>
  <!--this button is temporary. The function should trigger when the side is loaded an should loop itself!-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The code to move to the next image should be *inside* the `setTimeout()` callback.

Answer (score 0):

You must use setInterval callback instead of setTimeout.

Create `active` variable as global variable, give it null value.

In your `imagegallery` function, begin to check if `active` is null. If it isn't, update className attribute: `active.className = 'inactivecontent';`

Remove `setTimeout` block.

Create another function `myStartingFunction`. Inside `myStartingFunction` call `imagegallery();` and add `setInterval(imagegallery, 5000);` instruction.

Now in your div (id = trigger) replace `imagegallery()` by `myStartingFunction()`.

You call first `imagegallery()` in `myStartingFunction` because, the setInterval callback execute the Function passed as parameter every time passed in second parameter, and it will wait 5 seconds before execute `imagegallery()` first time.